# Azure AD Premium enterprise applications licensing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This is a licensing related question for Azure Active Directory.

We would like to use Azure AD as a SAML identity provider for our own applications, using the available method in the Azure AD Premium subscription, i.e. by creating a new custom application in the 'enterprise applications' list. Now do I need to assign a Premium license to every user that is going to login to this application via SAML? Or does it suffice to assign this license to the users that are administering the application?

The former case seems more plausible to me, however it would be way too expensive for us, and during testing the custom applications seems to work also for users which do not have the license.

Answer (score 1):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

I am not a licesing expert, that said, Azure AD licenses are per user. Read the doc above. If the app is pre-integrated in the gallery, Azure AD users with the free tier can connect to 10 apps at no cost. If the app is on-premises, that requires Azure Application Proxy which would require Azure AD Basic.

If it's a custom application not in the gallery AD Premium is required. Keep in mind AD premium has a ton more functionality. Conditional Access is a Game Changer. Very powerful. Multifactor Authentication, self service password reset, MIM, SCCM CALs, are all included.

Being able to simplify identity for users and link All applications they use to their AD account is important. Ems gives you the ability to monitor identity with Advanced Threat Analytics etc. It's actually a very useful suite of services and not drastically different in price than stand alone AD premium.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have purchased the Azure AD Premium license (a free license is available for non-profits for a small number of users), and am using it to link a custom enterprise application via SAML. Users that do not have the Azure AD Premium license assigned are also able to log in to the custom enterprise application via the Microsoft Access Panel. My original question was whether this is expected behavior or not. I.e., do I need to assign Azure AD Premium licenses to users that will only have to login to custom enterprise applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting point on [license page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/active-directory/) too

> Blockquote
>   With Azure AD Free and Azure AD Basic, end users who have been assigned access to SaaS apps can get SSO access to up to 10 apps. Admins can configure SSO and change user access to different SaaS apps, but SSO access is only allowed for 10 apps per user at a time. All Office 365 apps are counted as one app.